# vs2012 shortcut keys for moving lines of code

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2012

what are shotcut keys  in vs2012 ,which to copy a line of code then move down or up,and cut a line of code then move down or up??

the copy version:

```
printf("hello world");// press a shotcut key ,then ..
printf("hello world");// this line of code automaticly appear here.
```

the cut version:

```
printf("hello you");//press a shotcut key ,then this line **will be cut**,and then ..
printf("hello you");//this line of code automaticly appear here.
```

is there any shotcut key exists likes them?

Comment: does ctrl-c ctrl-v w/o any text selected work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift-Alt-T moves the line with the cursor down one line, I'm still trying to figure out how to move it up.

So after a little bit of googling it doesn't seem that VS has a keyboard shortcut to move a line up, which is quite baffling since the do have the above mentioned shortcut to move a line down. Anyway, you're definitely not the only one who wants this functionality and there are a few suggestions to this.

Either install this extension (free):
[MoveLine extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b3ee08dc-a28f-4aec-9efa-69215ab5ee52)

Or you could install ReSharper which is really, really nice in my opinion:
[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Answer (score 1):

You should try this explanation below:
http://www.herrodius.com/blog/52

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) extension adds support for this. It's the "Move Line Up/Down Commands" feature.

With this feature enabled <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> move the current line (or multi-line selection) up or down.

Usually the first thing I do when set up visual studio is install this extension, then turn off all the other rubbish it adds (weird document tabs, scrollbar etc) just for the move up and down